# What is the default application to open .ttf font files on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, file-association, default-settings

I've installed an application that comes with its own font viewer utility. The application has set it as the default for opening fonts.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: IMDisplay Font viewer]

I would like to know what the Windows 10 default is for opening font files, so that I can set it back as the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Windows Font Viewer]

The application is called Windows Font Viewer, and is located in `C:\Windows\System32\Fontview.exe`

Comment: I'm trying to set it as the default from the File Properties dialog box but it gives me the following error: “The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program.”

Comment: @KhalidHussain I could easily do the association. Did you right-click on the file, select Open with... -> More apps -> Look for another app on this PC and inputted `C:\Windows\System32\Fontview.exe`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, same error.

Comment: This is what I'm experiencing: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/cannot-set-windows-font-viewer-as-default-program/7d27f3c4-01c3-4fa3-a64e-32e52e263c0e

I'm not sure if I should ask this in a separate question.

Comment: Since the *informative* question you asked here has been answered, I think you should ask a separate *troubleshooting* question.

Comment: I found a solution: merge this [reg](https://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/44820d1402460186-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a-ttf.reg) file. Source [post](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8486-default-file-associations-restore-windows-8-a.html) is about Windows 8 but I checked and the values match those on my Windows 10 system.